# get realpath in solaris shell

Tags: shell, solaris

Is there utility in Solaris which can get realpath.

```
cd /home/me/test
realpath ..  # got /home/me in linux
```

I can do realpath in linux, but it seems lack on solaris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function realpath {
  [ -d "$1" ] && (
      CDPATH= \cd "$1"
      /bin/pwd
  ) || (
      CDPATH= \cd "$(dirname "$1")" &&
          printf "%s/%s\n" "$(/bin/pwd)" "$(basename $1)"
  )
}
```

Some comments:

While function is non POSIX, it is recommended to use it instead of the legacy `name() { ... }` syntax at least on ksh which is probably the most used shell under Solaris.

`\cd` is used vs `cd` to prevent something else than the `cd` shell builtin to be used and then avoid unwanted side effects.
`/bin/pwd` is used to call `pwd` as a non builtin command because it has no idea about how the parent shell went to the current directory and so can only get the real path of it.

Comment: After think again, my original question is 'realpath' replacement.  So jliagre's answer is proper.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old q&a, but it seems to me that the offered realpath function has two shortcomings. One, it changes the current working directory, which might be surprising after one (or more) calls to the function. Two, it seems to only work for directory paths. The following might be a more general function (I'm a bash user and only need this for scripts, so I skipped the backslashing.)

```
function realpath {
    local base=$(basename $1)
    local d=$(dirname $1)
    (cd $d ; echo $(/bin/pwd)/$base)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing my previous answer shortcoming. Beware that your suggestion will break when the path components contain spaces.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this on the Solaris 10 platform and here are the answers found (including a simplified version of jlliagre's answer)

Full Path, WITH symbolic links resolved:

- /usr/bin/pwd -P
- /bin/pwd          (Thanks: jlliagre )
- realpath {linux}

Full path, without symbolic links resolved:

- /usr/bin/pwd

The question one needs to ask oneself is, $( which pwd ) ?

Comment: Solaris pwd binary takes no argument, /usr/bin/pwd -P is strictly equivalent to both /usr/bin/pwd and `/bin/pwd.